# Get <html> element nested in a parent <html> element

Tags: html, parent-child

```
<html id="htmlparent">
  <html id="htmlchild">
  </html>
</html>
```

As a client accessing these html docs is there a way "htmlparent" can access elements inside "htmlchild"?

- Preferably with raw javascript although I would use jquery if I had to
- document.getElementsByTagName("html") doesn't work. This only returns the first  element in the doc

Edit> Evernote seems to have made it work. I'm trying to get all anchors inside the a webpage no matter how many  elements there are
[image]

Comment: That cannot possibly work. An HTML DOM cannot have more than one `html` element even if it tried. That is why getElementsByTagName() isn't working. *There is no second `html` element.*

Comment: Why do you have the second html element anyway?

Comment: Evernote do not have nested HTML elements. They have iframes displaying multiple HTML documents at once.

Comment: It's unclear why you feel like you really need to do this. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way an html element can nest under another html element. However, the iframe element

> represents a nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page
>   [[developer.mozilla.org]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)